# How can I accurately compare ports of URI objects in Java?

Tags: java, uri

This is my check.

```
URI firstURI = new URI("http://example.com:80");
URI secondURI = new URI("http://example.com/testing");


if (!firstURI.getHost().equals(secondURI.getHost()) || 
    !firstURI.getScheme().equals(secondURI.getScheme()) || 
    firstURI.getPort() != secondURI.getPort()) {
        //error
}
```

By default, if the protocol is `http`, then the port is `80`. So the above scenario should pass. But because the 2nd URI doesn't contain a port, `getPort()` returns `-1` and compares it with `80`. How can I account for default ports (`80` and `443`) for `http` and `https` protocols?

Comment: You know that the default port for http is 80, not 8080, right?  `http://example.com/testing` is a synonym for `http://example.com:80/testing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before testing the port, check if it is defined. And if not, then assign it its default value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  URI firstURI = new URI("http://example.com:80");
  URI secondURI = new URI("http://example.com/testing");

  boolean sameHost = firstURI.getHost().equals(secondURI.getHost());
  boolean sameScheme = firstURI.getScheme().equals(secondURI.getScheme());
  boolean samePort = getPort(firstURI) == getPort(secondURI);

  if(sameHost && sameScheme && samePort) {
    System.out.println("ok");
  } else {
    System.out.println("error");
  }

}

private static int getPort(URI uri) {
  int port = uri.getPort();
  // if port is undefined, set it to its default value depending on the scheme
  if(port == -1) {
    port = "https".equals(uri.getScheme()) ? 443 : 80;
  }
  return port;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `80` rather than `8080`?

Comment: his requirement is to use 8080, I'll add a note though

Comment: @user6800688 I changed the solution to use `80`, it should work now